# Word: Make cells independent

Tags: microsoft-word, documents, cells

I'm trying to make those cells (Title5 & Title6) separate from each other so I can resize one of them without moving second one, but I fail, whatever I do and apply to those cells.

[image: before inserting text]

This is what I get:
[image]

I can't move lower border of Title6 up.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not that clear to me.

But this is what I understand and hope it helps -

- Try to create new cells with the 'Draw Table' option, instead of using the 'Insert Table' Option.

[This is where you can find the 'Draw Table' option and how it looks in Word 2007](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xu74s.png)

- Be sure that it does not cross the cell that you want.[Not the cross tho the other columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aBa6z.png)

Comment: Those cells are created with "Draw Table" already. When I move cell Title6, cell named Title5 moves as well, they are connected and I can't remove connection.

Comment: How do you resize, Horizontal? If so, make sure that you do not cross the dotted highlighted line to the other columns.

Comment: It is what I'm talking about, I have a lot of information under Title1 and a bit less under Title3, I need to make cells under them to adjust space without making huge gaps. I place text under Title1, and it makes huge gap under Title3.

Comment: Still your question is not clear. which cell do you have a problem with? is it Title1 and Title3; or Title5 and Title6. Please show the proper snapshot if possible.

Comment: Now you have screenshot.

Comment: Alright, merge Title6 with the cell just above it and draw the cell for Title6 again with its lower border such that it is just above the upper border of Title5. This works for me.

Comment: What about if I need to put more text in Titlle3 and less text in Title1 later on? Then I need to merge and draw cells again. I'm looking for solution where space is adjusted automatically.

Comment: You can't! sad to say. But try this link http://www.wordbanter.com/showthread.php?t=91093